# make init.d script start at boot

Tags: debian

I have created the following file in /etc/init.d

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/ndppd

# Carry out specific functions when asked to by the system
case "$1" in
  start)
   ndppd -d
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/ndppd {start}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I then executed `chmod +x /etc/init.d/ndppd`

I want ndppd to run at startup, so I ran update-rc.d ndppd defaults

but when I run `update-rc.d ndppd defaults`

I get no output

Why is that? what is the proper way to make my init.d script to run the "start" section at boot?

Comment: What of the `stop` case?

Comment: @george I don't have a stop section, and I don't need one for this daemon. I need it to be running at all times. The issue I have now is that it does not start at boot.

Comment: Which version of Debian is this?  If it is Debian 8 or later, why are you even starting here with a van Smoorenburg `rc` script?  If it is Debian 9 or later, why are you not using what the ndppd package itself supplies?

Comment: @JdeBP I had no idea this was part of the repository. I'll just use that thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need a symlink in /etc/rc3.d to this file. The name needs to start with capital S and by convention then has 2 digits and a name like nppd.

The files are sorted by name, so the 2 digits effectively give the order.

In order to be able to use update-rc you need some magic comments in the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Provides:          ndppd
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs
# Should-Start:      $syslog
# Should-Stop:       $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start or stop the inetd daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

Should be at the beginning of the file write after #!/bin/sh -e